# Dynamic Menu Issue with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have to create a dynamic menu(based on the data). I have my directive like

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.directive('myMenu',function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'EA',
            replace : true,
            scope :{menu : "=menu"},
            compile: function(element, attributes) {
                var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes){
                    element.empty();
                    for (i = 0;i<$scope.menu.length;i++){
                        element.append("<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>"+$scope.menu[i].name+"</span></a></li>");
                    }
                }
                return linkFunction;
            }

        }
    });   
      mainApp.controller('MenuController', function($scope) {
          $scope.menu = [];
          var home = {name:"Home", subList:[{name:"Home1"},{name:"Home2"}]};
          var contact = {name:"Contact", subList:[{name:"Contact1"},{name:"Contact2"}]};
          $scope.menu.push(home);
          $scope.menu.push(contact);
      });
```

My HTML file is

```
<div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MenuController">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <my-menu menu="menu"></my-menu>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the contents mentioned in the li tags are coming properly as desinged. But I am trying to recreate them using the my-menu tag but the contents are not getting dispalyed properly. Below is the screenshot of the result

[image]

Why is the second home and contacts are not coming properly ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't have `id='cssmenu'` twice in your html document.

I guess you have something like `#cssmenu { ... }` in your css file but it will only be applied to the first element with `id='cssmenu'`

Comment: Even if I am having only one id='cssmenu' its the same.